# Reverse XSL output

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL and its XML output. Can I produce a sample input file using these? I need to see how the structure of the input XML needs to be.

Comment: Yes, you can, but not univoquely. Suppose the `f()` function from A to B and a1, a2 from A and b from B: by definition you could have `f(a1) = b` and `f(a2) = b`

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation why this cannot generally be done.

Comment: Good question, but I'm more interested in how you find yourself in a position where you have the XSLT and the output, but no access to the input. Is reconstruction by inverting the XSLT really the only way to get a sample input?

Comment: @Tom: For some strange marketing reasons if I remember correctly - we couldn't ask the client to give us the data before we had something that works to show

Answer (score 3):

> I have an XSL and its XML output. Can
>   I produce a sample input file using
>   these?

For any function `f()`to have a reverse, it is necessary that the `f()` is a bidirectional 1:1 mapping.

Not all functions are bidirectional 1:1 mappings. The simplest example that comes to mind is:

```
f(x) = x^2
```

So squaring isn't a bidirectional 1:1  mapping. Applying the reverse of squaring to `9` would have to produce two values -- `-3` and `3`, but by definition a function can produce only a single value.

Generally, if a function isn't a bidirectional 1:1 mapping, it is lossy, and not all information it has on input is present in (or can be deducted from) the result.

In the case of squaring the information that is lost is whether the argument was positive or negative.

There are functions that lose 100% everything, like the constants:

```
f(x) = 1
```

Typically an XSLT transformation is a function that transforms the source XML document to some output result. Generally such transformation is lossy (for example we often are told to discard/ignore some attributes or elements).

**Thus the answer whether the input to a transformation can be recovered from the output is generally negative**.

Even if not the exact input, but "a sample input" is necessary, this cannot always be produced and it will never contain the data that is lost by the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for that. I do not need the reverse to produce the same input though. If I start with file A and get file B after the transformation, the reverse transformation will take file B and produce file C (that is different from A). However a forward transformation from either file A or C produces B. I'm assuming there's not tool that does that though, and I've got no time to write it.

Answer (score 1):

You might get an idea of *some* of the original format, however it is likely that you will not be able to reconstruct the complete original.

If the XSLT does not use part of the original XML in order to construct the output, you can't reconstruct the original structure.

Additionally, if your XSLT is using templates correctly, it may be difficult to discern which templates were called when (and in particular how the original XML was processed).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's OK if I lose some of the original structure - I just need a sample input file. Do you know what tools I can use to do this?

Comment: @Michael - I don't know of any such tool. Probably because the flow is reversed (output -> input) and because an original can't be reliably reconstructed.